# Opening a window from another window in python using pyqt framework

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying open a pyqt window from another pyqt window on clicking a button  but i can't really get a hold do it . Both the python files opening.py and signup.py can run standalone on their own but i can't think of a way to link them ...(Running signup.py from opening.py after clicking signup button)

opening.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'opening.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Jan 20 00:19:45 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
#from signup import Ui_Dialog1

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,     _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(290, 237)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 19, 151, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 170, 201, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 201, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleTest1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.handleTest2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "MAIL SERVER", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SIGN UP", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "LOGIN", None))

    def handleTest1(self):

        #self.accept()       
        #self.h=Ui_Dialog1()
        #self.h.setupUi(QtGui.QDialog())        
        pass

    def handleTest2(self):
        execfile('login.py')

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and other file which is to be opened after clicking signup button (login button doesn't work as of now)

signup.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'abc.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Jan 19 23:35:37 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)


except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_Dialog1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        print "16"        

        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SignUp"))
        Dialog.resize(415, 364)
        self.SignUp = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.SignUp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 310, 176, 27))
        self.SignUp.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.SignUp.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)  
        self.SignUp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SignUp"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 66, 17))
        self.label_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 100, 66, 17))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 150, 66, 17))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 200, 121, 17))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 250, 91, 17))
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 181, 27))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 190, 181, 27))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_4"))
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 181, 27))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_5"))
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 40, 181, 27))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_6"))
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 240, 181, 27))
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_7"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.SignUp, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.SignUp, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        print "17"
        Dialog.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("SignUp", "SignUp", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Name", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "E-mail", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Confirm Password", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Mobile (+91)", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog1()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The commented part in opening.py is the one creating problems . Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Your Ui_Dialog1 should inherit from QDialog, which makes it an UI object, but you inherit from object, this has no "show" method.

```
def handleTest1(self):

        #self.accept()
        #self.h=Ui_Dialog1()     # You need to move this to __init__ function
        #self.h.setupUi(QtGui.QDialog()) # You need to move this to __init__ function
        self.h.show()  # call the show method here
```

You need to move the self.h = Ui_Dialog1() and setupUi to **init** functions, this will avoid possible memory leak. (otherwise each time you click "sigunup", it will create a new object)

Comment: If i do that and run opening.py instead of running this file it opens signup.py even if (self.h.show) is in handleTest1

Comment: and it gives "self.h.accept()
AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog1' object has no attribute 'accept'" error ..

Comment: It seems you are using "QtDesigner" to generate the code file, and you add your own logic function basing on that, am I right?  In your opening.py, Ui_Dialog inherit from object, this is not correct, you should inherit from QDialog, so that you can have QDialog.accept() defined, which wont' make self.accept() error